# Use the same mapply function to create several new variables

Tags: r, function, mapply

I have a data frame ("dat") in which each row represents one participant of a study. For each participant ("code") I have a column that gives their sex ("sex") and age ("age"), and several columns with test results ("v.1" etc.). The data frame looks something like this:

```
> dat
   code sex age v.1 v.2
1  A1   m   8   4   9
2  B2   f   12  7   2
```

For each column of test results, I need to look up the value in a corresponding vector outside the data frame (e.g. "v.1.m.8" for 8 year old male participants or "v.1.f.12" for 12 year old female participants) and insert the value from that vector into a new column in the data frame ("v.1.t"). There are different vectors for male and female participants and for different age groups. The vectors look something like this:

```
v.1.m.8 <- c(4, 5, 2, 8, 2, ...)
v.2.m.8 <- c(3, 2, 2, 1, 8, ...)
v.1.m.12 <- c(...)
v.2.m.12 <- c(...)
v.1.f.8 <- c(...)
v.2.f.8 <- c(...)
v.1.f.12 <- c(...)
v.2.f.12 <- c(...)
```

For me, the most logically straightforward way to look up values in the vectors is a for-loop with nestes if-statemenst. Sort or like this:

```
for (i in nrow(dat)) {
    if (dat[i, ]$age < 8 | dat[i, ]$age > 18) {
        dat[i, ]$v.1.t <- NA
        dat[i, ]$v.2.t <- NA
    } else if (dat[i, ]$age < 12) {
        if (dat[i, ]$dat.sex == "m") {
            dat[i, ]$v.1.t <- v.1.m.8[dat[i, ]$v.1]
            dat[i, ]$v.2.t <- v.2.m.8[dat[i, ]$v.2]
        } else {
            dat[i, ]$v.1.t <- v.1.f.8[dat[i, ]$v.1]
            dat[i, ]$v.2.t <- v.2.f.8[dat[i, ]$v.2]
        }
    } else {
        if (dat[i, ]$dat.sex == "m") {
            dat[i, ]$v.1.t <- v.1.m.12[dat[i, ]$v.1]
            dat[i, ]$v.2.t <- v.2.m.12[dat[i, ]$v.2]
        } else {
            dat[i, ]$v.1.t <- v.1.f.12[dat[i, ]$v.1]
            dat[i, ]$v.2.t <- v.2.f.12[dat[i, ]$v.2]
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid a loop, I might use mapply() in something like this way:

```
dat$v.1.t <- mapply(
    function(a, b, c) {
        if (a < 8 | a > 18) {
            NA
        } else if (a < 12) {
            if (b == "m") {
                v.1.m.8[c]
            } else {
                v.1.f.8[c]
            }
        } else {
            if (b == "m") {
                v.1.m.12[c]
            } else {
                v.1.f.12[c]
            }
        }
    },
    dat$age,
    dat$dat.sex,
    dat$v.1
)

dat$v.2.t <- mapply(
    function(a, b, c) {
        if (a < 8 | a > 18) {
            NA
        } else if (a < 12) {
            if (b == "m") {
                v.2.m.8[c]
            } else {
                v.2.f.8[c]
            }
        } else {
            if (b == "m") {
                v.2.m.12[c]
            } else {
                v.2.f.12[c]
            }
        }
    },
    dat$age,
    dat$dat.sex,
    dat$v.2
)
```

The problem with this second solution is that I would have to repeat the whole code for each variable I want to assign.

Is there a better solution?

*In my real code I have to look up eleven columns in 44 vectors to create eleven new columns.*

*I would prefer a solution with base R.*

Comment: How should the comparison to your outside vectors work? Like how do you determine which value of that vector you need to fill into the new variable in your dataset? `For each column of test results, I need to look up the value in a corresponding vector outside the data frame (e.g. "v.1.m.8" for 8 year old male participants or "v.1.f.12" for 12 year old female participants) and insert the value from that vector into a new column in the data frame ("v.1.t").` Are those names vectors and you look for the value in your data as the name in the vector and then choose the corresponding value?

Comment: @LeoP. "v.1.m.8" is the name of one of the vectors. The value for dat$v.1.t is the value in this vector that is in the position of the value of dat$v.1. E.g. `dat$v.1.t <- v.1.m.8[dat$v.1]`. Which vector is chosen depends on the age and sex of the participant. For example, the vector "v.1.m.8" contains the values for male participants younger than 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be simple with `ifelse()`.

The following example is for just one new variable:

Data example (thanks @Adam Quek):

```
dat <- data.frame(code = paste0(LETTERS[1:24], 1:24), sex=c("m", "f"), 
                  age=c(8,12, 12, 8), v.1 = sample(1:10, 24, replace=T),
                  v.2 = sample(1:10, 24, replace=T))
```

Vector examples:

```
v.1.m.8 <- c(21:30)
v.1.f.8 <- c(31:40)
v.1.m.12 <- c(41:50)
v.1.f.12 <- c(51:60)
```

Code for new variable `v.1.t`:

```
dat$v.1.t <- with(dat, ifelse(!(age %in% c(8,12)), NA, 
                          ifelse(age == 8 & sex == "m", v.1.m.8[v.1], 
                                 ifelse(age == 8 & sex == "f", v.1.f.8[v.1],
                                        ifelse(age == 12 & sex == "m", v.1.m.12[v.1],
                                               v.1.f.12[v.1])))))
```

The age restriction can easily be edited to include more categories and to branch out the possible vectors.

Output:

```
   code sex age v.1 v.2 v.1.t
1    A1   m   8  10   1    30
2    B2   f  12   6   5    56
3    C3   m  12  10   3    50
4    D4   f   8   7  10    37
5    E5   m   8   5   4    25
6    F6   f  12   6   9    56
7    G7   m  12   2   9    42
8    H8   f   8   2   3    32
9    I9   m   8   4   1    24
10  J10   f  12   7   4    57
11  K11   m  12   7   4    47
12  L12   f   8   9  10    39
13  M13   m   8   9   2    29
14  N14   f  12   5   8    55
15  O15   m  12   1  10    41
16  P16   f   8   8   4    38
17  Q17   m   8   6   7    26
18  R18   f  12   4  10    54
19  S19   m  12  10   1    50
20  T20   f   8   9   6    39
21  U21   m   8   9   8    29
22  V22   f  12  10   2    60
23  W23   m  12   6   6    46
24  X24   f   8   6   7    36
```

If you don't want to write the `ifelse()` for every of your 11 variables, put the vectors into a list with two layers (list of 11 lists with 4 vectors each) and `mapply()` over your variables and the list of vector lists.

Edit:

I thought about an implementation with `mapply()` and I think a simple `for()`-loop is easier.

The following should do it (example with two variables and 4 vectors each (m8, f8, m12, f12)):

Vectors:

```
v.1.m.8 <- c(21:30)
v.1.f.8 <- c(31:40)
v.1.m.12 <- c(41:50)
v.1.f.12 <- c(51:60)
v.2.m.8 <- c(61:70)
v.2.f.8 <- c(71:80)
v.2.m.12 <- c(81:90)
v.2.f.12 <- c(91:100)
```

List of vectors:

```
myvectors <- list("v.1" = list(v.1.m.8, v.1.f.8, v.1.m.12, v.1.f.12), 
                  "v.2" = list(v.2.m.8, v.2.f.8, v.2.m.12, v.2.f.12))
```

`for()`-loop (looping only through the names of the list, so `i` is `c("v.1", "v.2"))`:

```
for(i in names(myvectors)){
  dat[, paste(i, "t", sep = ".")] <- with(dat, ifelse(!(age %in% c(8,12)), NA, 
              ifelse(age == 8 & sex == "m", myvectors[[i]][[1]][eval(parse(text = i))], 
                ifelse(age == 8 & sex == "f", myvectors[[i]][[2]][eval(parse(text = i))],
                  ifelse(age == 12 & sex == "m", myvectors[[i]][[3]][eval(parse(text = i))],
                    myvectors[[i]][[4]][eval(parse(text = i))])))))
}
```

Output:

```
   code sex age v.1 v.2 v.1.t v.2.t
1    A1   m   8   3   2    23    62
2    B2   f  12   7  10    57   100
3    C3   m  12   2   3    42    83
4    D4   f   8   7   6    37    76
5    E5   m   8   2  10    22    70
6    F6   f  12   1   9    51    99
7    G7   m  12  10   6    50    86
8    H8   f   8   4   6    34    76
9    I9   m   8   3   1    23    61
10  J10   f  12   5   4    55    94
11  K11   m  12   5   5    45    85
12  L12   f   8   3   8    33    78
13  M13   m   8  10   9    30    69
14  N14   f  12   3   4    53    94
15  O15   m  12   6   2    46    82
16  P16   f   8   8   3    38    73
17  Q17   m   8   9   5    29    65
18  R18   f  12   5   6    55    96
19  S19   m  12   6   4    46    84
20  T20   f   8   2   9    32    79
21  U21   m   8   5   1    25    61
22  V22   f  12   2   1    52    91
23  W23   m  12   3  10    43    90
24  X24   f   8   2   9    32    79
```

With this, the only thing you would need to prepare is the list of lists of vectors with correctly named sublists on the first level (so `"v.1"` to `"v.11"` as shown above with `"v.1"` and `"v.2"`. Make sure that the order of the 4 vectors in the sublists is always the same! In my example the order is m8, f8, m12, f12. Hope it helps!

Comment: I've tried some solutions and a `for()`-loop will be the easiest, I think. See my edit for an example you could use. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Let say your data looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(code = paste0(LETTERS[1:24], 1:24), sex=c("m", "f"), age=c(8,12, 12, 8), v.1 = sample(1:10, 24, replace=T), v.2 = sample(1:10, 24, replace=T))
```

Split based on combination of sex and age and call out the v.1 value for each split:

```
lapply(split(dat, list(dat$sex, dat$age)), '[[', "v.1")

$f.12
[1]  1  9  2  3  3 10

$f.8
[1] 8 3 7 7 3 8

$m.12
[1] 10  3  2  2  4  1

$m.8
[1]  8 10  1  9  5  7
```

Split based on combination of sex and age and call out the v.2 value for each split:

```
lapply(split(dat, list(dat$sex, dat$age)), '[[', "v.2")

$f.12
[1] 10  3  5  8  9  2

$f.8
[1] 2 3 4 8 2 5

$m.12
[1] 9 7 1 1 1 2

$m.8
[1]  5  2  1  5  9 10
```

Edit: Thanks @Sotos for pointing out splitting by two variables

Comment: Thank you. How would I add the look-up in the external vectors?

Comment: what do you mean by "look-up in the external vectors"?

Comment: You can use `split` on two variables and avoid having to define `g`. Something like `lapply(split(dat, list(dat$sex, dat$age)), '[[', 'v.1')`

Comment: In my question, there is a series of vectors ("v.1.m.8" etc.) outside of and separate from "dat". For each value in "dat", I want to look up a value in one of those vectors. There are four vectors for each variable (or column) in "dat", one for each combination of sex and age group ("...m.8", "...m12", "...f8", and "...f12").

Comment: Do you mean that you have a vector that you want to insert into the current dataframe? Could you help clarify what is it you want to achieve in your solution? And also, please provide better reproducible example.